# How to setup HTTPS on Traefik locally?

Tags: traefik

I generated self-signed certificate and I wanted to configure HTTPS on Traefik locally

I used steps in the [docs here](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/tls/#user-defined) to add the labels, but it won't work on Chrome/Firefox

docker-compose

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.2
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:

      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.watch"
      
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:8443"
    
    labels: 
      traefik.http.routers.dash.rule: Host(`dash.localhost`)
      traefik.http.routers.dash.service: api@internal

      traefik.tls.certificates.certfile: /home/certs/localhost.crt
      traefik.tls.certificates.keyfile: /home/certs/localhost.key

      traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints: web
      traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme: https
      traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares: redirect-to-https

    networks:
      - traefik-network
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8443:8443"

    restart: unless-stopped
networks:
  traefik-network:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your container needs access to your certificates. Place them in a folder near your `docker-compose.yml` (e.g. `./traefik/certificates`).

You can give your container access by noting the directory under your volumes:

```
volumes:
    - ./traefik/certificates:/home/certs
    ...
```